# Sequelize OR condition object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

By creating object like this

```
var condition=
{
  where:
  {
     LastName:"Doe"，
     FirstName:["John","Jane"],
     Age:{
       gt:18
     }
  }    
}
```

and pass it in

```
Student.findAll(condition)
.success(function(students){

})
```

It could beautifully generate SQL like this

```
"SELECT * FROM Student WHERE LastName='Doe' AND FirstName in ("John","Jane") AND Age>18"
```

However, It is all 'AND' condition, how could I generate 'OR' condition by creating a condition object?

Comment: i've seen 3 ways or operator being used... `where: { $or : [ {attr:val}, {attr:val}] }` , `where : { $or : { attr:val, attr2:val} }` , `where: { attr: { $or: [val, val] } }`

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Seems there is another format now

```
where: {
    LastName: "Doe",
    $or: [
        {
            FirstName: 
            {
                $eq: "John"
            }
        }, 
        {
            FirstName: 
            {
                $eq: "Jane"
            }
        }, 
        {
            Age: 
            {
                $gt: 18
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Will generate

```
WHERE LastName='Doe' AND (FirstName = 'John' OR FirstName = 'Jane' OR Age > 18)
```

See the doc: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#where

Comment: This should be `$or: { ... }`. Note, the `[` and `]` should become `{` and `}`

Comment: I prefer this way before the and/or functional way @evanhadfield suggested since it's neater.

Comment: how would i do the following in sequelize?

...where (A or B) and (C or D)

Comment: Use `[Op.or]` now from sequelize, `const { Op } = require('sequelize')`, instead of `$or`, as your key for sequelize 5+. They changed them to symbols.

Answer (score 84):

String based operators will be deprecated in the future (You've probably seen the warning in console).

Getting this to work with symbolic operators was quite confusing for me, and I've updated the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#basics) with two examples.

```
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [{authorId: 12}, {authorId: 13}]
  }
});
// SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId = 12 OR authorId = 13;

Post.findAll({
  where: {
    authorId: {
      [Op.or]: [12, 13]
    }
  }
});
// SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId = 12 OR authorId = 13;
```

Comment: i've seen 3 way or operator being used... ` where: { $or : [ {attr:val}, {attr:val}] } ` , ` where : { $or : { attr:val, attr2:val} } ` , ` where: { attr: { $or: [val, val] } } `

Answer (score 40):

Use `Sequelize.or`:

```
var condition = {
  where: Sequelize.and(
    { name: 'a project' },
    Sequelize.or(
      { id: [1,2,3] },
      { id: { lt: 10 } }
    )
  )
};
```

[Reference](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/docs/models/) (search for `Sequelize.or`)

Edit: Also, this has been modified and for the latest method see [Morio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31390257/3341891),

Answer (score 33):

In Sequelize version 5 you might also can use this way (full use Operator Sequelize) :

```
var condition = 
{ 
  [Op.or]: [ 
   { 
     LastName: {
      [Op.eq]: "Doe"
      },
    },
   { 
     FirstName: {
      [Op.or]: ["John", "Jane"]
      }
   },
   {
      Age:{
        [Op.gt]: 18
      }
    }
 ]
}
```

And then, you must include this :

```
const Op = require('Sequelize').Op
```

and pass it in :

```
Student.findAll(condition)
.success(function(students){ 
//
})
```

It could beautifully generate SQL like this :

```
"SELECT * FROM Student WHERE LastName='Doe' OR FirstName in ("John","Jane") OR Age>18"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! You saved my life bro. 
I was getting error for ('Sequelize/type'), your detailed answer with import did help me.

Answer (score 26):

For Sequelize 4

Query

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE LastName='Doe' 
AND (FirstName = "John" or FirstName = "Jane") AND Age BETWEEN 18 AND 24
```

Syntax with [Operators](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html)

```
const Op = require('Sequelize').Op;

var r = await to (Student.findAll(
{
  where: {
    LastName: "Doe",
    FirstName: {
      [Op.or]: ["John", "Jane"]
    },
    Age: {
      // [Op.gt]: 18
      [Op.between]: [18, 24]
    }
  }
}
));
```

Notes

- Avoid [alias operators](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html)  `$` (e.g `$and`, `$or` ...) as these will be deprecated
- Unless you have `{freezeTableName: true}` set in the table model then Sequelize will query against the plural form of its name ( Student -> *Students* )

Answer (score 21):

See the [docs about querying](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/).

It would be:

```
$or: [{a: 5}, {a: 6}]  // (a = 5 OR a = 6)
```

Comment: Looks like the syntax has changed; this format no longer works (Sequelize 6.6.5 on my system).  From their docs: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#examples-with--code-op-and--code--and--code-op-or--code-

Answer (score 5):

```
where: {
          [Op.or]: [
            {
              id: {
                [Op.in]: recordId,
              },
            }, {
              id: {
                [Op.eq]: recordId,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
```

This Works For Me !

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are facing issue in making more complex query like -

```
// where email = 'xyz@mail.com' AND (( firstname = 'first' OR lastname = 'last' ) AND age > 18)
```

would be:

```
[Op.and]: [
    {
        "email": { [Op.eq]: 'xyz@mail.com' }
        // OR "email": 'xyz@mail.com'
    },
    {
        [Op.and]: [
            {
                [Op.or]: [
                    {
                        "firstname": "first"
                    },
                    {
                        "lastname": "last"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "age": { [Op.gt]: 18 }
            }]
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let options: FindOptions<any> = {}
let where: WhereOptions = [];

where.push({filedZ: 10});

if (query.search) {
        let tmp: WhereOptions = {
          [Op.or]: [
            {
              [Op.and]: {
                filedX: { [Op.like]: `%${query.search}%` },
              },
            },
            {
              [Op.and]: {
                filedY: { [Op.like]: `%${query.search}%` },
              },
            },
          ],
        };
        where.push(tmp)
}


options.where = where;

await some.findAndCountAll(options);
```

```js
let options: FindOptions<any> = {}
let where: WhereOptions = [];

where.push({filedZ: 10});

if (query.search) {
        let tmp: WhereOptions = {
          [Op.or]: [
            {
              [Op.and]: {
                filedX: { [Op.like]: `%${query.search}%` },
              },
            },
            {
              [Op.and]: {
                filedY: { [Op.like]: `%${query.search}%` },
              },
            },
          ],
        };
        where.push(tmp)
}


options.where = where;

await some.findAndCountAll(options);
```